# What’s the difference between inflation and inflation tax?

Tags: inflation, government-bonds, spending, government

I get that people seem to be using the term inflation tax as a metaphor for understanding inflation, but it seems to be a bit more than that. We all know that inflation reduces the buying power of our dollar, but I don’t see how “tax” is a useful metaphor for this notion. It *would* be a useful metaphor IF the goods and services we provide went to the government, but that’s only true for some. A business usually isn’t providing goods and/or services to the government, it’s usually to the general public or another business.

For the term “tax” to be used with inflation requires that the government funds their spending using inflation. But I don’t see how the government can fund their spending (effectively) using inflation.

Comment: You're just confusing, what is anyway a confusing discussion.  You often hear it said that:  ***"Inflation is sort of like a tax"***  It's just that simple.  (Some people agree with that, some do not - whatever, it's a political/economic discussion.)

Comment: It's called "inflation **tax**" because the *government has taken value from you* (by the act of printing more money they made your money has less values), which is the *same effect* the other taxes do.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's mostly semantics. Per [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AInflation_tax#:~:text=An%20inflation%20tax%20is%20the,that%20subtracts%20value%20from%20currency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AInflation_tax#:%7E:text=An%20inflation%20tax%20is%20the,that%20subtracts%20value%20from%20currency).

> An inflation tax is the economic disadvantage suffered by holders of
> cash and cash equivalents in one denomination of currency due to the
> effects of inflation, which acts as a hidden tax that subtracts value
> from currency.

Inflation itself is a highly complex phenomenon that is entangled with many aspects of economics, finance,  and politics. "Inflation tax" is simply "the effect of inflation on cash-like investments".

Comment: Calling something tax is usually to evoke an emotion.

Comment: @lalala I wonder if they'll start calling it "inflation theft" and then "inflation violence" and then "inflationcaust" if "tax" doesn't work well enough for them

Answer (score 17):

It IS going to the government. What causes inflation is when the government increase the money supply faster than the economy is growing.

Imagine a simpler monetary system with no fractional reserve banking and no electronic money. All money is paper bills. The government prints the paper bills, and then uses this paper money to buy things, thus inserting the new paper money into the economy.

So suppose that the economy of a certain place at a certain time is producing, say, 100 million unit of "stuff". There is 100 million dollars -- let's call the currency "dollars" for convenience -- in circulation. So each unit of stuff must cost $1.

Then the economy does not grow, but the government prints another $10 million of currency and uses it to buy things. What happens? There's still just 100 million units of stuff being produced. So there's now $110 million to buy 100 million unit of stuff. The price of each unit of stuff must rise to $1.10.

The government used this $10 million it printed to buy stuff. At the higher inflated prices, $10 million buys about 9 million unit of stuff. That 9 million unit of stuff would otherwise have been bought by private parties. So the government has taken 9 million units of stuff out of the 100 million, leaving only 91 million for private citizens. The government effectively taxed the people 9%. But the tax was subtle, because they didn't actually hand any currency over to the government. They paid the tax in the form of lower value for their money, i.e. an "inflation tax".

This isn't a hypothetical example. Many governments have tried to finance government programs by printing money. The result is pretty much always inflation.

Real life is more complex than my simple example. Most money today is not paper and coins but electronic entries on a computer. An increase in the money supply of X% does not necessarily result in EXACTLY X% inflation, because there's the issue of "velocity of money, that is, how many times is each dollar spent in one year. Etc. But the principle is the same.

Comment: Hmm, I see RonJohn changed my word "stuff" to "widgets". I don't want to get into an argument about it so okay, fine. But I understand "widget" to refer to one hypothetical product, whereas clearly in context I mean all the products produced by the economy, not just one. If you understand "widget" here to mean "all the different things produced by everyone in the country", okay. But please understand that that's what RonJohn means. We're not talking about one specific product.

Comment: Yes, widgets was not a good substitute. The only way to understand this is as an average, where all “stuff” contributes to a singular notion of economy (value of all good and services produced). That average value is artificially shifted by the injection of unearned money, causing the economy to look healthier than it is (there isn’t in fact 110 million worth of stuff, but the numbers suggest there is). A “healthier” economy has higher prices, but those higher prices came at the cost of government owned stuff (whatever they bought with the 10 million). Still think “tax” is a stretched analogy.

Comment: And is it true that the government can only inject money by purchasing things in the economy? Can’t they just add printed money into circulation? Isn’t that what the Fed does?

Comment: @Cybernetic How do you add it to circulation? You eitther give it someone in exchange for things (buying "stuff"), or give it to someone in exchange for their work (buying more abstract "stuff", but still "stuff").

Comment: "What causes inflation is when the government increase the money supply faster than the economy is growing." This is not the only source of inflation. Resource scarcity can play a role; see, for example, what happens when gas supply is impacted.

Comment: @ceejayoz You're confusing "increasing prices for some product" with "inflation". If there's a shortage of, say, gasoline, then the price of gasoline will go up relative to other products. In that case resources are diverted from other products and services. People may buy fewer movie tickets or steaks or whatever to pay for the higher gas cost. "Inflation" is when there is a general increase in prices and wages. The price of everything goes up. Of course the increase is not exactly the same for every product and service because all the factors that affect price are still operating.

Comment: @Jay I'm not confused at all. Inflation is literally measured by measuring the prices of a group of products. An increase in the price of gas increases shipping costs on pretty much everything; https://www.thebalance.com/gas-prices-have-outsized-impact-on-inflation-5181585. "The price of gas has swung so wildly that it’s been an important driver of changes in the overall CPI, despite making up just 3% of its “basket” of goods that government statisticians use to calculate inflation."

Comment: @Jay: “it [inflation] IS going to the government” -  usually true. But not always. Consider velocity of money… https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_supply: velocity of MZM correlates well to inflation, references often better than M0-M2. (can be tautologous because of how velocity is measured.) Money supply includes private bank credit, especially when no reserve requirement. Also consider countries that use the US dollar. also consider fixed money supply, fixed resources, growing population: inflation increases. Technology can increase velocity of money.

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO you could also just give every citizen a gift of 1$. That's arguably not the government buying stuff, but still likely a big part of it will be used by people to buy stuff.

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO What Paulo said is exactly what has happened with all the government stimulus... everyone that got simulus checks neither gave the government "stuff" nor worked for the government.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this answer. In addition to the things others have mentioned, it simply isn't true that inflation always follows when the rate of money creation exceeds the rate of growth in the economy. If, for example, the private sector decides to hold larger cash balances (perhaps due to uncertainty about the future), then the money supply must expand to accommodate that change, but it won't cause inflation.

Comment: @Nobody I specifically mentioned the issue of the velocity of money and referred to other complicating factors. Could one imagine a scenario where the velocity of money decreases, and the government creates exactly enough additional money to compensate for this? Sure. In such a case the government action would prevent deflation rather than causing inflation. I don't know of any case where this has actually happened in the history of the world, but it's certainly theoretically possible.

Comment: @michael Yes, one could imagine a scenario where the government creates money and just gives it to the citizens without taking any material goods or services in return. I was thinking of such things as among the complicating factors and it's a fair criticism of my answer that I did not spell that out.

Comment: @Jay You don't have to go that far back into history; this is what happened in the US in the wake of the 2008 financial crisis, and it was much talked about by economists at the time. And although your answer does talk about velocity of money in the final paragraph, but it comes across as raising the issue primarily to dismiss it; i.e., "it's just a fiddly detail and not important in practice". In fact, it's extremely important, and failing to understand it has led to a great deal of harm. There's also the fact that none of this is really relevant to the question that was asked.

Comment: @Jay you *really* don't have to go far back in history, it has been done for all four major currencies (USD, EUR, JPY, GBP) in the last 15 or so years https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_easing

Comment: On top of what other people said, this answer completely ignores the distinction between governments and central banks.

Comment: Why must the price of each unit rise after new cash is injected into the economy? This seems like a big assumption from a naive model about the economy.

Comment: @fqq Yes, I was trying to write a forum post and not a  book! Yes, governments like to pretend that the central bank is an independent organization for some reason. But they are organizations that only exist because they have been given special power and authority by the government. If you or I decided to create our own central bank tomorrow and started issuing regulations that we demanded banks follow, we would simply be ignored. If we tried to print money, we'd be put in jail for counterfeiting. By any conventional definition of "government", central banks are part of the government.

Comment: @cybernetic Because where else is the extra cash going to go? If today a certain place has $100 million in cash circulating, and tomorrow the government printed another $100 million in cash and handed it out to people, do you suppose that everyone would suddenly become twice as rich? That with all this extra money, someone who previously could only afford a 1 bedroom apartment could now afford a 2 bedroom apartment, etc? Where would all the new "stuff" come from? ...

Comment: ... Unless the economy is growing, there's still the same amount of stuff out there. If there's more money to buy it with, then inevitably prices must go up. (Or other technical adjustments happen, but that's getting into more complexity.)

Comment: @Jay So the actual mechanism behind prices increasing is the new (fake) demand caused by recently purchased stuff by the government, to which companies will respond to with higher prices. Correct?

Comment: @Jay the problem is that you ignore completely what has actually been happening for over a decade (quantitative easing) and important more recent policy (COVID stimulus etc), which contradict your answer. Regarding central banks, it does not matter much but for example the ECB is obviously not under the control of national governments.

Comment: Well, I've tried to explain what I think the large majority of economists would agree is pretty well established economic principles. I've said my piece and I see no point repeating it. I'll let others get the last word.

Comment: An important factor in this scenario is that when the government "prints another $10 million of currency and uses it to buy things.", well someone's going to have to do some work to make those things. Thus the hypothesis that "There's still just 100 million units of stuff being produced" seems to lack support. Indeed, in many cases the purpose of government spending is to cause more things to be produced. The vast amounts of extra work being done to design, manufacture and distribute sufficient covid-19 vaccines to fulfil government orders being a current example...

Comment: @Steve Ok, I'm not going to argue with anybody, but you bring up a factual issue. What you say is true, IF we assume that the "stuff" purchased by the government with the new money is produced in addition to what was being produced before. If everyone was working full-time and the government then issues contracts for $10 million worth of widgets and these contracts are filled by diverting production from other things, so that the total amount produced is the same, it's just the composition that has changed, then this will cause inflation. If the government contracts are filled by people ...

Comment: ... by people working overtime or previously unemployed people being hired to do the work, then it would not cause inflation. Of course reality might be somewhere in between, it's not necessarily 0% or 100%.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the best way to address monetary inflation by the government (a.k.a. money printing) is by referring to it as a "hidden tax."  Taking the US as an example, over the past 100 years, prices in the US have roughly increased by 5% per annum, and the purchasing power of the dollar has also dropped by about the same amount.  A fancy way of describing an increase in the US monetary base is the Fed "expanding its balance sheet."

Money printing via fractional reserve banking is an excellent way for a government to reduce its debt burden.  Due to something called the Cantillon Effect, when the Fed (or any other central bank) creates new currency, it gets to enjoy the full purchasing power of that newly created currency.  This currency can be used for all sorts of things, not the least of which are paying off debt obligations.  Governments love the inflation tax, because they don't have to explicitly ask citizens to pay it.  Instead, it happens under the covers, in stealth mode.  The problems arise, again due to Cantillon Effect, when the newly printed money works its way through circulation.  As that happens, prices of everything will tend to rise.  By the time the printed money reaches the average person, it buys less than the equivalent amount of currency held in the hands of citizens purchased, before the central bank printed that money.

Rest assured, central banks around the world, in particular the Fed and ECB, have every intention to try to print their way out of their current debt conundrums.  Only time will tell if they can do this without a loss of confidence in their currencies taking place.

Comment: So would it be better to just give everyone a bit of the new money?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann This has kind of happened, with all the stimulus programs happening.

Answer (score 2):

The "tax" in "inflation tax" is metaphorical.  It means that although you have, say $100, in your bank account, your actual purchasing power is less than you would expect because of inflation.  From your point of view it's as if someone came along and took a little bit of your money, like the tax man does.

It's actually quite common to use "tax" in this metaphorical way, even when the government isn't involved, and even when the resource being "taxed" isn't money.  For example, if your coworker Steve is overly chatty, then you might be reluctant to ask him a short question because of the "Steve tax" of having to listen to him talk about his favorite sports team for 5 minutes before you can get out of his office. See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tax, sense 2, for another example.

Comment: Just so. And you may hear lotteries referred to as a "tax on gullibility" (or stupidity, or hope, etc)

Comment: also: pink tax, which is interesting in the sense that while it's largely a market arising phenomenon rather than a formally delineated, legislated tax code, there are in fact real taxes on tampons, in particular, resulting in them being non-exempt and classified as "luxury" goods; also, price discrepancies can also arise due to higher import tariffs on some products designed for women. these complicated details induce confusion in people conflating real taxes with metaphoric ones. ( e.g. "repeal the pink tax"). (not trying to make feministic arguments. this is for informative purposes only)

Comment: Yep, both good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, inflation can actually result in a transfer of wealth to the government.

Inflation is bad for creditors and good for debtors, because while any monetary debts stay the same nominal value, the purchase power those debts represent decreases.

So when a government has a high amount of debt, then intentionally causing an inflation can be a way to reduce the purchase power of that debt. Which means that there is a net transfer of wealth to the government.

This is most obvious with those citizens who invested into government bonds, and will now receive a coupon which represents less purchase power than they invested.

But it is also indirectly the case with citizens who have their money in a regular bank account. Sure, you might think you are losing money to the bank, because they now owe you less wealth if you decide to withdraw your money. But where does the bank gets *its* money from? The central bank, which is run by the government. So indirectly you are losing that wealth to the government.